# Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.8 and I have an issue for some products

http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/com3

http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/com6

Those products exist in DB and I have Url records for those products.

Also it looks like urls with prefix com**X** don't go to web app. So I think this issue takes place before app. Probably some handlers remove access to com**X** urls.

For example:

http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/com7 - I have Server error

http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/com77- I have 404 error. This url handles by app.
com7 and com77 don't exist in UrlRecords

we are using standard nopCommerce configuration for handlers in web.config

```
    <handlers>
      <add name="SitemapXml" path="sitemap.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RobotsTxt" path="robots.txt" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="DenyAccessToPluginDLLs" verb="*" path="*.dll" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

any ideas?

Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is hard to say what could be the issue, would be great if you can provide[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct URL of the product? You can check the correct product URL in the NopCommerce Admin menu.

Go to **http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/Admin/Product/List** and choose the product that you can't find. Then click on the **'Edit'** button. In the edit page, on the top-right, click on the purple **'Preview'** button. It will open a new window with the correct URL of your product.

If there is an error during the preview, go to **http://snknop.cloud.rt.ru/Admin/Log/List**. You should have all the information about the error there.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. This issue takes place before app so there is no records in nopCommerce log. We checked it before writing this post.